# Millones y Millonas

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género, números

Viendo un video de Nicolas Maduro presidente de Venezuela el dice:

> Millones y millonas de Bolivar.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrXQkPOvI7A
en 0:42

¿Es correcto decir `millonas` o es un modismo en Venezuela?

Nunca antes había escuchado usar millonas.

Se que en este caso:

> Trescientos mil habitantes.
>
> Trescientas mil personas.

es correcto.

¿Cuál es la regla para asignar géneros a los números y si `millonas` es en algún caso correcto ya que nunca la he escuchado antes y no me suena para nada correcto?

Comment: Cuando salió la noticia todo el mundo se rió se eso. Creo que simplemente estaba emocionado, y de la costumbre de decir "hombres y mujeres, niños y niñas, trabajadores y trabajadoras", le salió "millones y millonas". Así que creo que no es un modismo, tan solo un lapsus linguae de Maduro.

Comment: Aprovechando la ocasion cual seria la regla para que alla corcondancia del numero entre genero y sustantivos como los ejemplos que puse

Comment: Indudablemente es un error. La primera regla para aprender español es nunca escuchar ningún discurso, alocución o cosa parecida del señor Maduro.  Al abrir google y digitar "brutalidades de " el buscador automáticamente lo completa y la búsqueda sólo retorna 14 mil resultados.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estimado, eso fue un error. Para este tipo de cantidades siempre es en masculino: millones, miles, cientos.

Ejemplos.

> Ellas son millones de trabajadoras.
>
> Ellas son miles de personas.
>
> Ellas son cientos.

Comment: Cierto para todos los ejemplos que dices pero cuidado porque alguien podría confundirse con el último ejemplo que das. "Ellas son cientos" es correcto. Pero también lo es "Ellas son trescientas trabajadoras", por poner un ejemplo. Por lo que, en general, no es cierto que para cantidades numéricas siempre se use el masculino.

Comment: No todos los sustantivos que hacen referencia a cantidades son masculinos. Los de tu ejemplo lo son, pero también tenemos otros femeninos como *decena*, *docena*, *centésima*...

Comment: si yo me equivoque me referia a esos tres (millones, miles, cientos ) perdon. (editado para que no se preste para confusión)

Comment: Existe alguna regla para determinar el genero?

Answer (score 0):

No es correcto decir millanoas y no es un modismo en Venezuela ni en otro lugar.

Es una lapsus, un error de este señor que tiene una educación no acorde con su cargo y se nota que lee muy poco, pues este es uno de muchos errores.