# ¿Cuál es la regla para asignar el género a cantidades numéricas?

Tags: género, números

Hace unos días pregunté sobre el caso de [Millonas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/millones-y-millonas). Sé que es un dísparate por decirlo del alguna manera. ¿Cómo lo sé? Por intuición, no sabría explicarlo mas que me suena a un dísparate.

En respuesta a esa pregunta sale que estas cantidades:

> cientos, miles, millones

Siempre se escriben en masculino, con lo que estoy de acuerdo.

Pero en un comentario a esa misma respuesta se aclara que hay otro tipo de cantidades que se escriben en femenino como:

> decena, docena, centésima

Entonces mi pregunta es **¿Cuál es la regla que rige este comportamiento?**

He tratado de buscar asociaciones que si los decimales(décima), que si las fracciones, pero docena se refiere a 12, como también se puede escuchar céntimo para referirse a una fracción de 100.

Comment: No lo tengo muy claro, pero me parece que decena, docena y centena son definidos como términos femeninos debido a que se trata de grupos de unidades(fémenino). Es decir, los términos completos serían, por ejemplo: una decena de unidades, una centena de unidades, etc.

Comment: @JoseMaria Siguiendo con tu serie, lo siguiente sería un millar de unidades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He encontrado una regla para asignar el género a los números en el RAE. El punto número 3 de ese artículo.

[Más Info](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rqV8h362gD62vc21qB)

> 3- Los cardinales, cuando son sustantivos, son siempre masculinos: el tres, un millón. Cuando funcionan como adjetivos o como pronombres carecen de variación de género, a excepción de **uno** y sus compuestos (→ uno, 2), que tienen formas específicas para el femenino: una, veintiuna, treinta y una, etc.; y de los correspondientes a las centenas, a partir de doscientos, cuyos femeninos adoptan la terminación -cientas (salvo quinientos, que tiene forma propia y cuyo femenino es quinientas): doscientas, trescientas, etc. El género del numeral lo determina el sustantivo al que se refiere: De las trescientas páginas que tiene el libro, me he leído cuarenta y una. En el caso de las centenas, el cardinal en función adjetiva debe concordar necesariamente en género con el sustantivo al que cuantifica, tanto si lo precede inmediatamente (doscientos kilos, trescientas toneladas) como si entre ellos se interpone otro elemento, por ejemplo, la palabra mil, si se trata de numerales complejos (doscientos mil kilos, trescientas mil toneladas). En lo que se refiere al cardinal uno y sus compuestos, la concordancia es obligada cuando el numeral precede inmediatamente al sustantivo: treinta y un kilos, veintiuna toneladas (no veintiún toneladas); pero si entre el numeral y el sustantivo femenino se interpone la palabra mil, la concordancia de género es opcional (→ uno, 2.2): veintiún mil toneladas o veintiuna mil toneladas.

Casi todos los puntos tratados ahí tienen casos especiales como:

Al final del punto 6.

> 6- mientras que el plural miles es un sustantivo masculino sinónimo de millares (→ mil): miles de euros, muchos miles de personas, etc.

En el punto 8 se puede encontrar este fragmento:

> 8- Cuando el cardinal con valor ordinal se pospone a un sustantivo femenino, es posible la concordancia de género: la página doscientas, la habitación trescientas doce; pero suele ser más frecuente el uso en aposición del sustantivo masculino que corresponde al nombre del número: la página doscientos, la habitación trescientos doce.

Answer (score 7):

No existe ninguna regla en los casos referidos a grupos de unidades, como no la hay en la mayoría de los casos en lo que se refiere al género de las palabras. ¿Por qué, cuando hablamos del tamaño de una persona, *estatura* es femenino y *peso* es masculino?

En cambio, sí existe esta regla en el caso de los sustantivos formados por sustantivación de adjetivos, eliminando el sustantivo original: esos son todos femeninos. El motivo es que, por ejemplo, *una centésima* equivale a *una centésima parte*; al ser *parte* femenino, *centésima* también lo es.

Esto mismo sucede en otros casos. Por ejemplo: los colores son masculinos, independientemente de su terminación o del género de la palabra que los origina, porque la palabra *color* es masculina. Así, *rosa* es femenino si nos referimos a la flor, pero masculino si nos referimos al color porque *el rosa* es una sustantivación procedente de *el color rosa*.

Answer (score 1):

Los números son elementos abstractos sin género, por tanto utilizan el género neutro. El género neutro en castellano, a menudo, coincide con el masculino (caso de millones, cientos, miles, etc...), pero hay casos en los que no es así (decena, docena, centésima, etc...).

No hay reglas para asignar género a las palabras, los conceptos abstractos pueden tener un género si se pueden asociar a un elemento que tenga género, en caso contrario tienen género neutro.