# Is "número" masculine or feminine?

Tags: género

**English:**

Consider this sentence "Mi habitación es la número cinco." Why couldn't "número" be masculine as in "el número cinco"? Does it have something to do with the gender of "habitación"?

I'm asking this question because I'm sure I've heard "número" as a masculine noun before.

**Español:**

Considere esta frase "Mi habitación es la número cinco." ¿Por qué no podría "número" ser masculino, como en "el número cinco"? ¿Tiene algo que ver con el género de la "habitación"?

Estoy haciendo esta pregunta porque estoy seguro de que he oído "número" como un sustantivo masculino antes.

Comment: related http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5182/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-regla-para-asignar-el-g%C3%A9nero-a-cantidades-num%C3%A9ricas/5196#5196

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed.  What's happening is there's an omited word(s).  For example, if I'm describing the room, I can use any of the following:

- Mi habitación es la grande.
- Mi habitación es la del fondo.
- Mi habitación es la que tiene mi maleta.

Returning to your phrase:

- Mi habitación es la **habitación** número cinco.

*número X* is itself a "short" hand for ordinal numbers (and also whenever labels include non-numbers, like 3B) in which you're really saying *con el/del número X*, where it is more obvious why *número* stays in the masculine as it's being used as an actual noun.  Effectively, *habitación número cinco* es the same as *quinta habitación*.  (Doesn't seem like much of a short hand until you get, say, *aula número 2579*, or *dos milésima quingentésima septuagésima nona aula* and you remember that ordinal numbers are a PITA after about 30. )

Answer (score 1):

Because you are getting the gender out of Habitación (which is femenine) not from número
For instance using cuarto (room), which is masculine the same phrase would read
mi cuarto es el número cinco

Answer (score 1):

That's an `Elipsis nominal`. **La número 5** means **La habitación número 5** and so that `habitación` has feminin gender, it's said **La número 5**.

There are other types of "Elipsis" like `verbal` i.e. 
**Lo bueno si breve, dos veces bueno** -> **Lo bueno si es breve, es dos veces bueno.**

, `preposicional` and 
`oracional` 
**A Pepe le gusta el helado, a Luis no.** -> **A Pepe le gusta el helado, a Luis no le gusta el helado.**

Kind Regards